# how to pull 1 button to the left and 2 button to the right in react>

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I got "continue" button on the position i want. how do I pull-right "check as guest" and "sign up & checkout" button to the most right?
[image]

```
<div className="row cart-buttons">
                                <div className="col-3">
                                    <Link
                                        to={`${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/`}
                                        className="btn btn-solid"
                                    >
                                        continue shopping
                                    </Link>
                                </div>
                                <div className="col-9">
                                    <div className="row">
                                        <div className="mr-2">
                                            <Link 
                                                to={`${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/checkout`}
                                                className="btn btn-solid"
                                            >
                                                check out as guest
                                            </Link>
                                        </div>
                                        <div className="col-5">
                                            <Link
                                                to={`${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/login`}
                                                className="btn btn-solid"
                                            >
                                                sign up & check out
                                            </Link>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

> If using Bootstrap

```
<div className="row cart-buttons d-flex justify-content-between">
    <div>
        <Link to={`${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/`} className="btn btn-solid">
            continue shopping
        </Link>
    </div>
    <div>
        <Link to={`${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/checkout`} className="btn btn-solid">
            check out as guest
        </Link>
        <Link to={`${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/login`} className="btn btn-solid">
            sign up & check out
        </Link>
    </div>
</div>
```

> If using Your css classes

```
<style>
    .menu {
        display:flex;
        justify-content:space-between
    }
</style>

<div className="row cart-buttons menu">
    <div>
        <Link to={`${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/`} className="btn btn-solid">
            continue shopping
        </Link>
    </div>
    <div>
        <Link to={`${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/checkout`} className="btn btn-solid">
            check out as guest
        </Link>
        <Link to={`${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/login`} className="btn btn-solid">
            sign up & check out
        </Link>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as i understand you want to push the `sign up and checkout & check as guest` **buttons** to extreme right and your question belongs to `react.js` category. You can change the class keyword to `className` and use the code.

```css
.holder
{
  background-color: lightgray;
  display: flex;
  padding: 2%
}

.left-side 
{
  flex: 25%
}

.right-side
{
  flex: 75%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

button 
{ 
  margin-left: 1%; 
}
```

```html
<div class="holder">
  <div class="left-side">
    <button>Continue shopping</button>
  </div>
  <div class="right-side">
    <button>Checkout as guest</button>
    <button>Sign up and checkout</button>
  </div>
</div>
```